# Is there any application like Proxyfire?

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, proxy

In Windows7 I using *Proxyfire* to pass through the internet filtering.

Now I am using Ubuntu and I looked everywhere and read many posts but still  cant find any easy app.

Can anyone help me?

By the way, I tried using *proxychain* but unfortunately that was really un-user friendly

Answer (score 0):

try this [Surrogafier 1.9.1b](http://bcable.net/project.php?surrogafier)